# Portability issue with template function Instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++builder, function-templates, c++builder-xe2

I'm porting a project from `MSVC` to `Borland C++` and I'm running into difficulties with `template functions`. For example, the following

```
void fn(const char *buffer)
{
  vector<string> output;
  boost::split(output, string(buffer), is_any_of(","));
  // ...
```

causes a compiler error:

```
[BCC32 Error] example.cpp(208): E2285 Could not find a match for 'split<SequenceSequenceT,RangeT,PredicateT>(vector<string,allocator<string> >,string,is_any_ofF<char>)'
```

whereas the modified example

```
void fn(const char *buffer)
{
  vector<string> output;
  string sBuffer(buffer);
  boost::split(output, sBuffer, is_any_of(","));
  // ...
```

compiles fine.

The generalization of this problem, as indicated in the post title, is that in certain cases `BCC` does not seem to match the template function if arguments are passed in as temporary objects that are constructed inside the function's argument list.

Before changing all the affected code, I'd like to understand why `BCC` thinks the first example is wrong. Is this a deficiency of the compiler, or does my code not comply to `C++` standards?

I'm using `RAD Studio / C++ Builder XE2`.

Comment: "I'm porting a project from MSVC to Borland C++" oh I pity the hells in which you must suffer.

Comment: "I'm porting a project from MSVC to Borland C++" I stopped reading at this point.

Comment: Does `boost::split` take the argument by reference, `const` reference or value? If the first, it is right to error because you can't bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary.

Comment: This is just a guess but if boost::split takes a reference as the second argument I think you need to create the object before and pass it in.

Comment: Well, thanks for the condolescences. If you want to know the details, I'm reverting a migration from BCC to MSVC, which has proven to be infeasible... so it is in fact "hell and back again".

Comment: @SethCarnegie and dutt: good point, I'll have a closer look.

Comment: @dutt and SethCarnegie: you are both right. `split` takes a reference for its first and second argument, but not its third argument. This explains everything but the fact that MSVC does not even print out a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because the function is a template; it's because for some reason it takes its `Input` argument as a non-`const` *lvalue* reference, as documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id819641.html):

```
template<typename SequenceSequenceT, typename RangeT, typename PredicateT> 
  SequenceSequenceT & 
  split(SequenceSequenceT & Result, RangeT & Input, PredicateT Pred, 
        token_compress_mode_type eCompress = token_compress_off);
```

In standard C++, you can't bind a temporary *rvalue*, such as `string(buffer)`, to such a reference. In Microsoft's imaginative reinterpretation of the language, you can.

The solution is to do exactly what you've done: introduce a named, non-temporary variable which can be passed by reference.

Answer (score 3):

From the Boost manual

```
template<typename SequenceSequenceT, typename RangeT, typename PredicateT> 
  SequenceSequenceT & 
  split(SequenceSequenceT & Result, RangeT & Input, PredicateT Pred, 
        token_compress_mode_type eCompress = token_compress_off);
```

It seems like the function does indeed take its parameters by reference, so your "workaround" is actually the correct way of using it.

MSVC is known to allow binding to a non-const reference as an "extension".